# pch file showing error in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, xcode6.1

I have run my project on Xcode 6.1 and it showing below error:-

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/abhishek_v/Downloads/IOS App-2/Reliant_sep_17productionwithAFN/Reliant/Reliant-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

After that I have search the pch file in project it shows red,after that i have deleted that file.

After deleting the file,again run the project but it showing same error.

I have added the screenshot which will give you the better picture on this issue[image]

Comment: Yes, It won't show in build phases.

Comment: For xcode Project .pch file is important without that you are not able to run any project. So either find original file in project folder or create new project and import everything from current project to new and do required setting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it again in the projet. You've removed the reference (deleted red file). So simply re-add it to the projet and it'll be ok.

Use a search on your computer to find it.

If it does not exist anymore, you can create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the path of the full path of the Pch file in target and project in your Xcode. Thats all